# Window functions in SQL: why are they called window functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I understand window function but don't understand why they are called window functions. When we say the "window" is it both the partition and the order by clauses?

Comment: Because they operate over a "window frame" -- a set of rows relative to the current row, which can be specified with more precision using the `ROWS` or `RANGE` keyword.

Comment: *"Also where can I post such questions without getting downvoted?"* If you have questions about how an RDBMS works, you are better off on [dba.se].

Comment: @GordonLinoff: So basically if I have `AVG(COL) OVER (PARTITION BY COL2 ORDER BY COL3 ROWS  BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED  FOLLOWING` then it is not "really" a window function. I could just calculate the average and join it to the raw data...

Comment: @GordonLinoff: i.e. the `ROWS` or `RANGE` keywords are why the are called window functions... Right?

Comment: @David . . . That is a window function.  That you could get the same result through some other method doesn't matter.  Also note that `ROWS`/`RANGE` are optional and usually the default window frame is used.  The defining syntax is `OVER`.

Comment: A very good question IMO. It looks like the term has been borrowed from [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Hi Gordon, can you please say what the difference between data manipulation and data transformation is? E.g. Is a window function manipulation or transformation? Thanks.

Comment: @David . . . I don't know what the difference is between those two concepts.  Window functions are just another function that can be used in a `SELECT` query (and in some other queries as well).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Window functions operate on a range of rows, defined by the OVER clause. It is like you are looking through the window, you see sky, star, moon. You are not seeing the whole sky, you see part of the sky.

I came across this beautiful definition of `window Function` in simple-talk website. I am reproducing below for more clarity.

[Original article on Simple-talk on window functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/)

> Window (also, windowing or windowed) functions perform a calculation
> over a set of rows. I like to think of “looking through the window” at
> the rows that are being returned and having one last chance to perform
> a calculation. The window is defined by the OVER clause which
> determines if the rows are partitioned into smaller sets and if they
> are ordered. In fact, if you use a window function you will always use
> an OVER clause. The OVER clause is also part of the NEXT VALUE FOR
> syntax required for the sequence object, but, otherwise it’s used with
> window functions.
>
> The OVER clause may contain a PARTITION BY option. This breaks the
> rows into smaller sets. You might think that this is the same as GROUP
> BY, but it’s not. When grouping, one row per unique group is returned.
> When using PARTITION BY, all of the detail rows are returned along
> with the calculations. If you have a window in your home that is
> divided into panes, each pane is a window. When thinking about window
> functions, the entire set of results is a partition, but when using
> PARTITION BY, each partition can also be considered a window.
> PARTITION BY is supported – and optional – for all windowing
> functions.
>
> The OVER clause may also contain an ORDER BY option. This is
> independent of the ORDER BY clause of the query. Some of the functions
> require ORDER BY, and it’s not supported by the others. When the order
> of the rows is important when applying the calculation, the ORDER BY
> is required.
>
> Window functions may be used only in the SELECT and ORDER BY clauses
> of a query. They are applied after any joining, filtering, or
> grouping.